# cmd- comma to separate parameters Compared to space?

Tags: c, command-line, windows-xp, cmd

I have some questions on the subject, of commas compared to space, in delimiting parameters.

They are questions that C programmers familiar with the cmd prompt, may be able to throw some light on..

I know that when doing

```
c:\>program a b c
```

there are 4 parameters `[0]=program`  `[1]=a` `[2]=b` `[3]=c`

According to `hh ntcmds.chm` concepts..

Shell overview

```
; and , are used to separate parameters

; or , command1 parameter1;parameter2  Use to separate command parameters.
```

I see `dir a,b`  gives the same result as `dir a b`

but

`c:\>program a,b,c`
gives parameters  [0]=program  [1]=a,b,c

So do some? or all? windows commands use ; and , ? and is that interpretation within the code of each command, or done by the shell like with space?

And if it is in the code of each command.. how would I know which do it?
I notice that documentation of explorer.exe mentions the comma,e.g. you can do 
`explorer /e,.`

but DIR /? does not mention it, but can use it.  And a typical c program doesn't take , as a delimiter at all.. So is it the case that the shell doesn't use comma to delimit, it uses space. And windows commands that do, do so 'cos they are (all?) written to delimit the parameters the shell has given them further when commas are used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two differences here between Unix and Windows:

- Internal commands such as `DIR` are built into the shell; their command line syntax doesn't have to follow the same rules as for regular programs
- On Windows, programs are responsible for parsing their own command lines. The shell parses redirects and pipes, then passes the rest of the command line to the program in one string

Windows C programs built using Visual Studio use the command line parser in the Microsoft C runtime, which is similar to a typical Unix shell parser and obeys spaces and quotation marks.

I've never seen a C program that uses `,` or `;` as a command line separator. I was aware of the special case for `explorer /e,.`, but I'd never seen the `dir a,b` example until just now.

Comment: How can you tell what is done by the shell, and what is done by the MS C runtime or standard lib? I have a windows c prog with just #include <stdio.h> At the top,and code for displaying argv. compiled with gcc.I can't see a way I can see which "parameterization!"is done from the shell and which is automatic from the standard library.Also, I notice comma doesn't work for the external programs xcopy or telnet.I think i've seen it for rundll32. I guess it's just some.Maybe not a function in a publicly available library!Maybe just exceptional ext programs doing it aping internal cmds of cmd.exe

Comment: Everything is done by the MS C runtime except shell functionality. Shell functionality includes things like redirection (`<`, `>`, etc. `>>`), piping ('|'), flow control (`&&` and `||`) and escaping (`^`).

Like I say, I've never seen a program that uses `,` on the command line, so I'm not suprised that copy and telnet don't support it.

Comment: are you suggesting ms c runtime does delimiting spaces and quotes? or is that still shell?  and if it's ms c runtime, can you prove it? I don't see how your second bullet point is distinguishing unix and windows 'cos wouldn't unix shell also parse redirects and pipes.

Comment: MS C runtime does spaces and quotes. I don't have it in front of me, but you can confirm using the MS C runtime source that's supplied with Visual Studio. I agree the Unix shell also does redirects and pipes; I was pointing it out for the purposes of clarity.

Comment: I believe you, but how do you know.. have you studied the c source files there?  or did you read about the windows c libraries?

Comment: I looked at the source code. It's straightforward when looking at a C program in the Visual Studio debugger: you look up the call stack at the function that called `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Batch files use a comma or semicolon as an alternative argument separator.

Test batch file:

```
@echo %1/%2/%3
```

Test run:

```
> test.cmd 1,2,3
1/2/3
> test.cmd 1;2 3
1/2/3
```

And, as you note, `dir` uses it, `copy` as well – those are both shell built-ins and probably run through a similar parser like batch files as well (it isn't exactly the same, since you can do things like `cd..` or `dir/s` which aren't possible for anything else). I guess (note: speculation) this is some sort of backwards compatibility that goes back into the DOS or even CP/M days. Nowadays you probably should just use spaces. And as Tim notes, the C runtime dictates certain things about arguments and how they are supposed to be parsed. Many other languages/frameworks follow that convention but not necessarily all. PowerShell for example has completely different argument handling and this can sometimes be a surprise when interacting with native programs from within it (that being said, PowerShell cmdlets and functions are no programs executable elsewhere, but batch files likewise).

Comment: you wrote "PowerShell cmdlets and functions are no programs executable elsewhere, but batch files likewise"   should that no be a not, and the but, removed? batch files as you say, likewise, can't be run from powershell, so i don't see why there is a 'but' there.

Comment: Interesting observation about `cd..` and `dir/s`. The only case I knew of until now that didn't bork on doing that was `ipconfig/all`, and that's not even a built-in.