# Can't output certain line to batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm using a batch file to create an RDP file using various variables to populate the contents.

Every line uses an Echo command and then outputs to a file with >>
For instance -

```
@echo screen mode id:i:1>> "C:\TEMP\file.RDP"
@echo use multimon:i:1>> "C:\TEMP\file.RDP"
```

Whilst this works for every line, one single line is giving me a problem and will not output -

```
@echo selectedmonitors:s:2,0>> "C:\TEMP\file.RDP"
```

For some reason, this line actually outputs *selectedmonitors:s:2,* (the 0 disappears) to the command window and outputs nothing into the .RDP file.
Whilst @echo selectedmonitors:s:2,0 works in the command window and outputs as expected, I can't output to a file.
What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

`>>` is just an abbreviation for `1>>`, where `1` is an output stream.
There are ten of those streams:
`0` is STDIN (Input) and not allowed for redirecting output.
`1` is STDOUT`("normal" output),`  2 `is STDERR` (error output)
and 3 to 9 are not defined (but usable).

Remove the `@` to see what happens:

A batch file like

```
echo selectedmonitors:s:2,0>>file.txt
```

shows as executed command:

```
echo selectedmonitors:s:2, 0>>file.txt
```

which tries to redirect Stream 0 (STDIN) (which holds nothing here) to the file.

The reason your other lines are working is that `,` is a standard delimiter and `:` is not, so the comma snips the zero off the echo and adds it to the redirection while the colon doesn't.

Two possible workarounds:

```
>>file.txt echo selectedmonitors:s:2,0
(echo selectedmonitors:s:2,0)>>file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, instead.

```
@(echo selectedmonitors:s:2,0)>> "C:\TEMP\file.RDP"
```

Without the parentheses, and since the `,` comma works as a delimiter in batch command lines (see [cmd- comma to separate parameters Compared to space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156438/cmd-comma-to-separate-parameters-compared-to-space) for example) the last token in the command is parsed as `0>> "C:\TEMP\file.RDP"` which literally means "*append stream 0 output to the given file*". Since stream 0 is the standard input stream, this is invalid and ignored, but the "0" parameter gets "eaten" in the process.